# Password generator : 'When button pressed the password won't show up in label'

Tags: python, tkinter, button, random, label

I was making a password generator. I want to make a program using tkinter. When you push the button the text should change to a random password which is generated, but it won't work

Can someone help me with this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time
import tkinter.font as font
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q','r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y','z']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q','R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y','Z']
c = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
d = ['!', '#']

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Password Generator")
root.configure(bg='white')
root.geometry('300x100')

bf1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=16, weight='bold')
bf2 = font.Font(family='Times', size= 24, weight='bold')

def changetext():
    psw = ''.join(random.choice(a + b + c + d)for i in range (9))


#btn1 = tk.Button(root, text = 'button1', command=changetext)
#btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
#button1 = tk.Label(root, text="Generate password")
#button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack(pady=20)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Change the text", command=changetext)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'won't work'?  While you've set the command to be ```changetext```, you haven't really changed anything in your ```changetext()```.

Comment: [edit] the title and body to include the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the label to show the generated password:

```py
def changetext():
    psw = ''.join(random.choice(a + b + c + d) for i in range (9))
    # show the generated password
    label['text'] = psw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do in One-Liner.

```
def changetext():
    label.configure(text=''.join(random.choice(a + b + c + d)for i in range (9)))
```